# How to get the list of IOptions available from DI in c# Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

Following this post: https://blog.bredvid.no/validating-configuration-in-asp-net-core-e9825bd15f10

I m now available to validate the Settings when a service need it. What I would like to do is to validate directly when the server starts in program.cs.

I m not sure how to do it? Is there a way to get the list of services injected in DI then verify if the type is assignable from IOption and register it?

Here is how I add to DI the Settings:

```
    //App settings
    services.ConfigureAndValidate<AuthenticationSettings>(Configuration);
    services.ConfigureAndValidate<SmtpSettings>(Configuration);
```

The extension code:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAndValidate<T>(
            this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
            IConfiguration config,
            string section = null
        ) where T : class
        {
            var configType = typeof(T).Name;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(section)) { 
                section = configType;
            }

            return serviceCollection
                .Configure<T>(config.GetSection(section))
                .PostConfigure<T>(settings =>
                {
                    var configErrors = settings.ValidationErrors().ToArray();
                    if (configErrors.Any())
                    {
                        var aggrErrors = string.Join(",", configErrors);
                        var count = configErrors.Length;
                        throw new ApplicationException($"Found {count} configuration error(s) in {configType}: {aggrErrors}");
                    }
                });
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> ValidationErrors(this object obj)
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results, true);
            foreach (var validationResult in results)
            {
                yield return validationResult.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my current launcher:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            /// <---- BEGIN / AN IDEA OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO ---->
            /// <---- THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING ---->
            var allServices = services.GetAllServices();
            if (allServices != null)
            {
                foreach (var service in allServices )
                {
                    if (service.ServiceType.IsAssignableFrom(IOptions))
                    {
                       services.GetRequiredService<service.ServiceType>()
                    }
                }
            }
            /// <---- END ---->
        }

        await webHost.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions in comment.

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT 1:
Thanks Steven for your help, with your answer, it helped me to continue to find an answer, but things are still missing.

now, all my settings inherit from ISettings, like:

```
public class AuthenticationSettings : ISettings
{
    [Required]
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ExpirationDurationInDays { get; set; }
}
```

I update Program.cs like:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;



var options = services.GetService<ILifetimeScope>()
   .ComponentRegistry
   .Registrations.SelectMany(e => e.Services)
   .Select(s => s as TypedService)
   .Where(s => s.ServiceType.IsGenericType && s.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IConfigureOptions<>))
   .Select(s => s.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
   .Where(s => typeof(ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(s))
   .ToList();
```

so now I need to instantiate each option in options and get the Value. I m still working on it. let me know if you have any suggestion or the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following suggestions from Steven, here is my solution:
My settings validator service

```
    public SettingsValidator(
        IServiceProvider services,
        ILifetimeScope scope
    )
    {
        var types = scope.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
            .SelectMany(e => e.Services)
            .Select(s => s as TypedService)
            .Where(s => s.ServiceType.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(IConfigureOptions<>)))
            .Select(s => s.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .Where(s => typeof(ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(s))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var t in types)
        {
            var option = services.GetService(typeof(IOptions<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { t }));
            option.GetPropertyValue("Value");
        }
    }
```

in startup:

```
        builder.RegisterType<SettingsValidator>();
```

example of Settings

```
public class AzureStorageSettings : ISettings
{
    [Required]
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Container { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

extensions

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(this Type givenType, Type genericType)
    {
        foreach (var it in givenType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
                return true;
        }

        if (givenType.IsGenericType && givenType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
            return true;

        Type baseType = givenType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null) return false;

        return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
    }
}
```

in program.cs

```
using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Starting settings validation.");
                services.GetRequiredService<SettingsValidator>();
                logger.LogInformation("The settings have been validated.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while validating the settings.");
            }
        }
```

Let me know if it works for you too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of configured option types by iterating the `IServiceCollection` instance:

```
var configuredOptionTypes =
    from descriptor in services
    let serviceType = descriptor.ServiceType
    where serviceType.IsGenericType
    where serviceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IConfigureNamedOptions<>)
    let optionType = serviceType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
    select optionType;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In Program.cs, I dont have yet IServiceCollection, I try to get it from services.GetRequiredService<IServiceCollection>() but It doesnt work. How could I get it?

Comment: Unless you explicitly store the IServiceCollection somewhere, it will be gone after the ServiceProvider is built using that collection. But its not possible for you to have this collection "yet" as it was available before. It's the object you call `AddTransient` and `AddSingleton` on.

Comment: I found a way using Autofac, I will update my question soon, but I still didn t find a complete answer, it s closed :)

Comment: This collection is available inside the Startup class.

Comment: I updated my answer, I m now able to get the list of the type of the settings. Do you know how to do something like: services.GetService(IOptions<typeof(configuredOptionTypes [0].GetType()))

Comment: `.GetService(typeof(IOptions<>).MakeGenericType(configuredOptionTypes[0]))`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I posted the final answer :) Let me know if you have any suggestions.